# Recover after ssd upgrade

Tags: keyboard, hard-drive, imac, ssd, mouse

27” IMac crapped out with no recent backups. After research settled on it was hard drive related. Swapped out hard drive for ssd and can get to Os Catalina screen where I select the ssd to install the recovery but I can not select anything. Also my mouse does not work. I assume it doesn’t work because the Bluetooth is off, but no sure. How do I select this without a mouse. I got that far using the space bar and tab button, but it will not work now. I’m just before slamming this expensive paper weight on the floor.

Comment: Assuming your question is how to get Catalina installed but your Bluetooth mouse won’t  work, just use a wired mouse or a wireless mouse with a unifying receiver like Logitech.